# SAS and DBSASTYPE

Tags: sas

I have this working for one column:

```
PROC APPEND base=MMUSAGE.bc_ent_jas_radius (dbsastype=(max_date =date9.))
data=work.radius_master force;
RUN;
```

But I have a second column name `MIN_DATE` that I also want to format as `date9.` on the `PROC APPEND`. Is it possible?

Comment: Please provide a working code example as well as the expected output. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

DBSASTYPE is for going the other way. When you are reading from an external database you are telling SAS what type to translate into.  It wants a type name (like you would use in PROC SQL) not a format specification.

DBTYPE is the option that tells SAS what type to create in the external database.  You need to specify the type using the syntax of the remote database.  It will only have any effect if the BASE dataset did not already exist before the PROC APPEND step.

If you just want to attach the DATE9. format to MAX_DATE use a FORMAT statement.

```
PROC APPEND base=MMUSAGE.bc_ent_jas_radius data=work.radius_master force; 
  format max_date date9. ;
RUN;
```